# regex store string of undertemined size

Tags: regex, json, text

I have strings in quotes that I want to store and replace. It is a long JSON script that I want to tweak without doing it manually. There are a lot of values in "quotes" because that is the syntax.

```
"Variable" : { 
     definitions
  }
```

I wanted to find these variables of underdetermined length using

```
"(\w)" : \{
    definitions
\}
```

but it isn't working. TextWrangler's grep is not finding anything.
I think \w is just for a single character, is there a way to find and store an undetermined amount of characters? I wanted to use a wildcard like * but this was giving me error or not finding anything

What should I be using?

Comment: "What should I be using?" What you should really be using is a proper JSON parser :)

Comment: actually it is a python script that takes a specially formatted xml document and outputs JSON to a particular specification. There was a tedious part where I needed to convert a template JSON into the way the python would be recreating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\w*` or `\w\*` will match zero or more alphanumeric/underscore characters; whether a backslash is required before `*` depends on the specific regex implementation.  Alternatively, you can use `\w+` or `\w\+` to match one or more `\w`s.

Comment: gah! I was so close to begin with, I had since done the majority of it manually. Thanks for the quick response!